# NoClassDefFoundError: SupportedEllipticPointFormatsExtension after Glassfish restart

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, glassfish-5

I have a simple t2 instance in AWS, I had to change the default timezone on which the RDS DB instance was running on; since no changes were being reflected, I decided to **reboot** the RDS instance.

Once this happened, the EC2 instance on which my `Glassfish 5` runs on started to fail, the app was returning an error trying to connect to the database.

I decided to **reboot** the EC2 instance as well (I'm new to AWS).

After this, I have no access to my webapp so I went on to connect to the EC2 instance via SSH and `./asadmin restart-domain [my_domain]`.

I noticed that after a couple of minutes, the webapp was just not working and showing a 500 error on a blank page so I decided to `tail -f server.log`

An ran into the following exception when restarting the domain:

> [WARNING] [] [org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain]
>   [tid: _ThreadID=44 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis:
>   1524271134399] [levelValue: 900] [[   GRIZZLY0013: Exception during
>   FilterChain execution java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   sun/security/ssl/SupportedEllipticPointFormatsExtension
>           at sun.security.ssl.HelloExtensions.(HelloExtensions.java:84)
>           at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeMessage$ClientHello.(HandshakeMessage.java:362)
>           at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:223)
>           at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:984)
>           at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:924)
>           at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:921)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1379)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLUtils.executeDelegatedTask(SSLUtils.java:274)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.doHandshakeStep(SSLBaseFilter.java:708)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.doHandshakeStep(SSLBaseFilter.java:622)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.handleRead(SSLBaseFilter.java:334)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ]]

Seems to be some sort of problem with SSL but I just can't get my head around it.

Any insights will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you restarted, you must have gotten a new version of Java. Glassfish 5.0 does not work with Java 8u161 or later: https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/issues/22416